# Experience cloud sites self registration: password policies error message language

Tags: apex, experience-cloud, passwords

We have a few Experience Cloud sites, with custom login and self registration pages. The registration is with a password, and in the backend, Community Portal users are created. Those users can be of different profiles. Each profile may or may not have different password policies defined and we want to let those policies enforce themselves (instead of hardcoding regex in the custom components). This works as expected, but we have a problem: the error messages are shown in english and we need them in spanish.

I know those messages actually translate automatically to the User's locale, because in our custom change password component that can be used when logged in to the site, those messages are translated. BUT as in the registration page, that doesn't happen. Maybe because the User isn't commited as an exception is throwned so the message is generated in the default language, but I need to change this.

Of course, creating custom labels in Spanish for every password policy is not an option, as that is impossible to manage in code.

The language for all these Sites is set to Spanish already:
[image]

Is there another setting somewhere? I didn't find in the profiles (even checked Site Guest User profile).

Any workaround is appreciated.

EDIT:

The user creation is handled in Apex code, and this is the part that handles the setting of password:

```
    try {
        u = [select id, firstName, lastName, profileId , Username from User where email =: email and ContactId =: contact.id];
        if([select name from network where id =: Network.getNetworkId()].name.contains('Sembrá Evolución')){
            Site.validatePassword(u, password, password);
        }
        System.setPassword(u.id, password);      
    } catch (Exception e) { // si la contraseña no cumple con las password policies del profile
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) throw error('Error al asignar la contraseña: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
```